# Database Tables - To decouple or not?

Tags: database

Is it better to create tables that store a lot of data that are related to an entity (User for example) or many tables to store said data?

For example:

User Table

- Name
- Email
- Subscription Id
- Email Notifications
- Permissions

Or

User Table

- Name
- Email

Subscription Table

- User ID
- Subscription ID

Notification Table

- User ID
- Receives?

... etc

Please consider code in this as well, or I would have posted to ServerVault.

Comment: its called normalisation, and yes, you should normalise.

Answer (score 0):

From a relational design standpoint what is important is the normal form you're aiming for.  In general, if the "column" would require multiple values (subscription_id1, subscription_id2, etc) then it is a repeating group, and that would indicate to you that it needs to be moved to a related table.  You've provided very general table and column notes, but taking a cue from the fact that you named "Email Notifications" and "Permissions" with plurals, I'm going to assume that those require related tables.